# How to optimize for loops and rbinds with large datasets

Tags: r, loops, rbind

I am currently working on a large dataset (~1.5M of entries) using R - a language I am not yet completely familiar with.

Basically, what I try to do is the following :
I want to check what happens during a time interval after "Start".
"Start" represents a few temporal values within every "Trial", and "Trial" represents all of the trials recorded for one "Reference".

So for each Reference, i want to check all Trials and see what happens after "Start", during this Trial

It's not so important if what i'm trying to do is still obscure, the thing is that I want to check every data in my dataframe.

My instinctive (understand, R-noob-ish) way of programming this function led me to a piece of code which I know is far from being optimized, and takes a LOT of time to run.

```
My_Function  <- function(DataFrame){
counts <- data.frame()
  for (reference in DataFrame$Ref){

  ref_tested <- subset(DataFrame, Ref == reference)
  ref_count <- data.frame()   

    for (trial in ref_tested$Trial){ 
      trial_tested <- subset(ref_tested, Trial == trial)

        for (timing in trial_tested$Start){
          interesting <- subset(DataFrame, Start > timing  & Start <= timing + some_time & Trial == trial) 
          ref_count <- rbind(ref_count,as.data.frame(table(interesting$ele)))
        }

     }
  temp <- aggregate(Freq~Var1,data=ref_count,FUN=sum);
  counts <- rbind (counts, temp)
  } 
return(counts)
}
```

Here, *as.data.frame(table(interesting$ele))* can have different lengths, and thus, so do *ref_count*.

I failed to find a way to grow my dataframe without using rbind, but I also know that given the size of my output it is not time-efficient at all.
Also, I have already programmed in other languages such as Python or C++ (a long time ago) and also know that having 3 consecutive for loops usually means that you're doing it wrong. But then again, I did not find a way to avoid doing that in this particular case.

So, do you have any advice on how to use R, or one of its package, to avoid such a situation?

Thank you in advance,

K.

---

EDIT :
Thank you for your first advices.

I tried the 'plyr' package and was able to reduce the size of my code chunck - it does as expected and is more understandable.Plus, i was able to produce some example data for reproductivity. See :

```
    #Example Input
    DF <- data.frame(c(sample(1:400,500000, replace = TRUE)),c(sample(1:25,500000, replace = TRUE)), rnorm(n=500000, m=1, sd=1) )
    colnames(DF)<-c("Trial","Ref","Start")
    DF$rn<-rownames(DF)

    tempDF <- DF[sample(nrow(DF), 100), ] #For testing purposes 

    Test<- ddply(.data = tempDF, "rn", function(x){

       interesting <- subset(DF,

                        Trial == x$Trial &
                        Start > x$Start  &
                        Start < x$Start + some_time )

       interesting$Elec <- x$Ref
       return(interesting)
    })
```

This is nice, but I still feel like it is not the way to go ; in this example, we only browse 100 observations, which takes ~4sec (I used a system.time()), but if i want to scan the 500000 observations of DF, it'd take more than 5 hours.

I have checked data.table but I am still trying to understand how to use it for now.

Comment: For a start, your three loops only need to loop over `unique(DateFrame$Ref)`, etc - at the moment you are repeating the calculation for each row, even though the `subset` will be the same.

Comment: Using `unique` inside for loops would help, otherwise we are looping through every row instead of group. Also, consider `lapply(split...)`. Try to provide minimal reproducible example data.

Comment: You can probably make use of `dplyr` and its `group_by` facility here - that would be much faster. We'll need to see some example data, though.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Providing example data that are relevant is a bit difficult, because the script doesn't make sense if I it runs on less than 100 observations. If that can give you an idea, I have 20 Ref, and approx 1000 Trials, with a variable amount of 'Start' in each Trials.

Comment: It would be useful to know what sort of data you have - e.g. the output of `str(DataFrame)`.  I tried your code with some made-up dummy data and just ended up with a load of zeros, so it would be helpful if you could explain what the output is supposed to represent.

Comment: Check out the `data.table` package. It's very efficient with large data, and I think you can achieve the for loop results using the grouping capabilities of the package.

Comment: Thank you again for the answers. I have edited my post with my latest code chuck and some example data.